# Unable to add a AD Security group (which does not have email address) inside the recipients for a "Grant Access to an item or folder" action

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

We have this security group named "Sales Manager - Sec" (which does not have email address):-

[image]

and we are trying to add this group inside a "Grant Access to an item or a folder" >> now we can search for the group>> but if we select it it will not be populated:-

[image]

[image]

so can we add a security group which does not have an email address inside the recipients list for "Grant access to an item or folder" action ?

Comment: I think we need more clarity on what you are trying to do.  AD groups do not have email addresses.  Exchange object do and those can be tied to AD objects, but the email address comes for Exchange.  What type of AD group is it (global, domain local, etc.)?  Are you sure it isn't an MS 365 group?

Comment: @DubStep yes it is MS 365 group as shown in my first picture

Comment: It sounds like you need to use a distribution group here possibly?  From looking at the picture closely, this seems to be a Power Automate (now Flow) question vs a SharePoint question, so I'm not much help there, sorry.

Comment: @DubStep distribution lists cannot be added to SharePoint permissions.. also this is a mix between power automate and sharepoint question, since i ma uisng a power automate action to update sharepoint item permission

Answer (score 0):

Since this Flow activity sends an email, it looks like it doesn't support AD security groups because they don't have an email address.

You will probably need to take an alternative approach if you wish to set permissions for this group, I would look at doing this via the REST api and with a "Send an HTTP request to SharePoint" activity.

This post might be helpful for you

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Flow-for-setting-up-item-permission-over-REST-API/m-p/1288826/highlight/true#M146676